# Resize div width as browser height is changed using CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

Have been searching for a few days for a CSS only solution to maintaining aspect ratio of a div. The important part is that the div height should be as the browser window height (without scrolling and without hiding overflow), and the width percentages should adjust to keep the aspect ratio correct. Everything I've found so far (mostly the padding trick) uses the parent element's width to maintain aspect, and adds a lot of extra space below the div, especially in  full screen on large displays.

Really trying to avoid javascpript.

Here is my basic setup:

::Edit:: added link to jsfiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/SUbYB/
::Edit 2:: just using jQuery to handle set width of div based on height. Thanks all!

stylesheet

```
body, html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.super-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 69.8%;
    height: 95%;
    max-width: 2008px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15.1% 0 15.1%;
    background: rgba(200,200,200,.2);
}
.aspect-container{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: rgba(200,200,200,.4);
}
.aspect-critical-content{
    position: absolute;
    top:0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background: rgba(200,0,0,.2);
}
```

and html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div class="super-container">
     <div class="aspect-container">

         <div class="aspect-critical-content">
         </div>

     </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle or a plunker?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SUbYB/ jsfiddle link to above code

Comment: you could try to use calc, if cross-browser is not too important for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fcalc

Comment: I would also recommend having a look at my own question. There was some useful input there, although no good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824709/how-to-make-a-flexible-square-fit-to-either-height-or-width-of-the-window-with-p

Comment: The only other pure css solution - i can think about, is to use break-points for max-height. but this probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks hugo, good stuff there. Looking more and more like this is something that can't be done with *just* css

Answer (score 0):

What's about just using:

```
display: table;
display: table-row;
display: table-cell;
```

That would look like in your case (additionaly to your code):

```
.aspect-container{
    display: table-row;
}
.aspect-critical-content{
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
}

.aspect-container2{
    display:table-row;
    height:100px;
}
```

and html:

```
<div class="super-container">
  <div class="aspect-container">
    <div class="aspect-critical-content">
      some text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aspect-container2">
    <div>
      text2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The second row I've added just to show how you can easily to play with height of another block within the same container.

[The code on plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/NC3fOCcQF8cKX87lO6dr)

Comment: tried this, but the aspect container (and children) won't resize to the correct width as the height decreases or increases.

Comment: Not sure I follow how is the height is related to the width in your comment.

Comment: Currently, in every solution I've tried, the height of the div will adjust as the width of the browser is changed. I need the width of the div to adjust as the height of the browser is changed.

Comment: Sorry, to adjust to what?

Comment: ... to adjust to whatever length maintains the aspect ratio, without exceeding the borders of the browser window (never scroll).

Comment: The sample code I've provided is just all about managing height problem. Width(s) usually do not have similar problems and generally are straight forward to manage. (I was just expecting you are easily able to to that with something like 'width:100%'). If you still experiencing certain problems with scroll bars appearing, that might be just because of some nuances with your own implementation. (Be sure also, that your `body` tag has padding:0; margin:0; properties set up).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css-technique:

```
.aspect-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* this is a aspect ratio of 1:3 */
  padding-top: 33.33%;
  position: relative;
}

.aspect-critical-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

The value of padding-top to the base of 100 is the aspect ratio.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mE4qG/

Comment: thanks, but padding and margin draw their values from the width of the parent element. I need the height of the window/parent element to be the driving factor in setting the size of .aspect-critical-container. It's looking more and more like this is not just a CSS solution.