# width equal to dynamic height square

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic, height, width

Is it possible with either css or js to set the width of an element to match it's height when the height is a % of the parent div. The child div also needs to change size if browser window is resized.

**Example**

```
body, html {height: 100%}
.parent {height: 100%; width: 960px;}
.child {
    height: 50%; 
    width: same as height; /* but not 50% of 960px, so that the child div is square*/
}
```

I'm trying to achieve something like this but width rather than height.
[Height equal to dynamic width (CSS fluid layout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout)

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Javascript, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can set the `width = height` or vice-versa in the `resize()` function.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ev6Vj/173/

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('#main').height($('#main').width());
});
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
</div>
```

```css
#main {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: #000 thin solid;
    background: #DDEEFF;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Just drag the `result` frame and watch the height match up with the width which is `100%` the width of the frame.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        $("div").height($("div").width());
    });
    $(window).resize();
});
```

You can do something like this using jQuery to match the height and width of an element.

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery.

```
function resizeChild() {
var child = $(".child");
var parentSize = child.parent().height();
child.height(parentSize / 2);
child.width(parentSize / 2);
}
$(window).ready(resizeChild);
$(window).resize(resizeChild);
```

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/mrTSX/9/)