# CSS 100% height on width

Tags: css

Is it even possible to make my width 100% of height using only CSS? Without using Javascript or the like.

```
{
    width: /*100% of height*/
}
```

Comment: As the `img` tag has square dimensions(in chrome), you can use it to give your element square dimensions. Something like this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/ygxdu/2/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are new css units for this

```
width: 100vh;
```

This means that the width of the element will be 100% of the viewport height.

> CSS3 has some new values for sizing things relative to the current
>   viewport size: vw, vh, and vmin.
>   One unit on any of the three values is 1% of the viewport axis.
>   "Viewport" == browser window size == window object. If the viewport is
>   40cm wide, 1vw == 0.4cm.
>
> 1vw = 1% of viewport width 1vh = 1% of viewport height 1vmin = 1vw or
>   1vh, whichever is smaller 1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger ([css-tricks post](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/))

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

PS: Support for these new properties is actually quite good in modern browsers. [See here](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)

Comment: There you go with description: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

Comment: @Rohit Azad https://gist.github.com/acdha/5397507/raw/018e760a9ae03adc6296f0f45f4b8c4fd290b87a/map.html

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you **very** much! (I'll accept after 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

This question [Height equal to dynamic width (CSS fluid layout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout) seems to have a good CSS-only answer by Nathan Ryan. It's also worth reading the comments below his answer for additional explanation. I hope this helps.

If you find the solution too complex, it might be worth giving more context to what you are trying to achieve in case someone has a good, alternative solution.