# How to make height equal width with css

Tags: javascript, html

How to make height equal width with css.

I have HTML like that :

```
<div style="width:900px;height:200px;">
<a style="display:block; float:left; width:35%; background:green"></a>
</div>
```

Now, I'd like to make height of `a` element equal width (35%). How can I do that? Thank your help.

Comment: You mean that you want to resize it proportionally?

Comment: He wants the height to be equal to the width, when the width is a percentage.

Comment: Well, I can put the height:auto... But I will check somethings.. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `window.getComputedStyle` to get the computed width, then do calculations to get the equvialent percentage that will make it the same size as the width.

HTML

```
<div class="someDiv" style="width:900px;height:200px;">
   <a class="someAnchor" style="display:block; float:left; width:35%; background:green"></a>
</div>
```

JS

```
var anchor = document.querySelector(".someDiv .someAnchor");
var astyle = window.getComputedStyle(anchor);
anchor.style.height = astyle.width; //this will make it static though

//to make it a percentage like width so it will expand and contract with resize of parent element

var pstyle = window.getComputedStyle(anchor.parentNode);
var pheight = parseInt(pstyle.height);
var awidth = parseInt(astyle.width);
anchor.style.height = ((awidth/pheight)*100)+"%";
```

Note that the anchor element will be bigger than the div height wise, to keep it inside the parent you will have to scale it down.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GvZNX/1/)

Comment: he has javascript tagged

Comment: And the title: 'with css', well I will wait to a ans.. :P You had make it with js and me with CSS... :P

Comment: Well. I am looking for this. Thanks Patrick Evans a lot.

Comment: second part has errors, editing to resolve.

Comment: Ikillnukes. Sorry. Only css cannot solve this problem. Thank for all suggestions.

Comment: There is nothing amiss.

Answer (score 10):

**Well I have that:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class='box'> 
    <div class='content'>Aspect ratio of 1:1</div> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box{
    background:#000;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;     /* desired width */
}
.box:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/wGszc/

http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

You can adapt it to your needs...

**And...** A little search in google doesn't hurt: https://www.google.com/search?q=make+height+iquals+to+width

Comment: this does not do anything at all what he wants, http://jsfiddle.net/wGszc/1/, the inner element is not same width and height, you have just simply made the parent element have same height width.

Comment: If the parent element has same height and width and you specified only with: that's the solution! Or not?

Comment: you're missing the content css .content {
        position: absolute;
        top:      0;
        left:     0;
        bottom:   0;
        right:    0;
}

this is a duplicate question anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout