# Plotly control relative lengths of each axis

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

maybe there is something in the documentation that I missed, but how do I control the relative length of each axis, so that the plot is a square?
I am basically looking for the equivalent of matlabs

```
pbaspect([1 1 1])
```

This is the current image [image]

which I want to turn into this (ignore the additional axis labels):
[image]

I made the change by manually setting the image size, but there has to be an easier way to do it.

```
fig.update_yaxes(scaleanchor = "x",scaleratio = 1,)
```

Does not work since the axes are using different numbers.
I am happy about any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's as simple as setting the **height** and **width** as the same

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=np.linspace(0,100,1000), y=np.random.uniform(0,5,1000), mode="markers"), layout={"height":400, "width":400})
```

#### approach 2 - use HTML view port heigh / width

- [css width same as height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799852/css-width-same-as-height) technique can be used
- create a `<div>` that is sized in same view port units.  embed **plotly** html within this sized `<div>`

```
import plotly.express as px
import io

buffer = io.StringIO()

go.Figure(
    go.Scatter(
        x=np.linspace(0, 100, 1000),
        y=np.random.uniform(0, 5, 1000) * np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000),
        mode="markers",
    )
).update_layout(margin={"t":0,"b":30,"l":0,"r":0}).write_html(buffer, full_html=False)


# use HTML techniques create a "square", NB height and width defined in same view port units
html = '<div style="width: 70vh; height: 70vh;">' + buffer.getvalue().encode().decode() + "</div>"
with open("example.html", "w") as f: f.write(html)

# not required if not running in jupyter
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
HTML(html)
```

Comment: Well yes, I am aware of that. But is there a way without having to set it manually? I want the image to open fullscreen while having the right properties without having to mess around with the image size everytime I run my code on a different screen.

Comment: ok - you can use HTML techniques to achieve this.  updated with an example

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I am currently trying to get it running in Pycharm, but there are some things that I don't understand (especially since I know very little about plotly and nothing about html). For example the last line of code. How is this applied to the final image?

Comment: ok - have updated to save to a file so you can just open it.  display in jupyter is handy if that's your dev env

Comment: This works. Thanks for taking the time to help me. I am honestly surprised that such a basic feature is not part of plotly and requires a workaround.