# How to resize circle div dynamically?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, resize

Circle should take all available container height and depend on it. Circle width should be the same as height. How to make circle width depend on height? Current behavior:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.circle {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">
    i
  </div>
  <div>
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Needed behavior (width & height shouldn't be hardcoded):

[image]

If container height changes it should influence circle height & width too

Comment: this is not a circle, this is a rectangle with rounded corners. for a real circle you may use SVG.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;` property, which is now supported in [all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio).
Also check [original aswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69116933/21251815).

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.circle {
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">
    i
  </div>
  <div>
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex-basic` to set initial main size for `.circle`.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.circle {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">
    i
  </div>
  <div class='text'>
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```