# Drawing a Square with width:50% in CSS?

Tags: css, height

I would like to display a square on a "mobile" WebApp. The width should be half of the screen size. On any screen. How to declare the height?

```
#square{
    position:absolute;
    background:black;
    width:50%;  
}
```

And how would I center such elements, with no fixed size?

thank you very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6615994/2464634

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something along these lines:

```
.sq{
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 0;
    background: red;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2ZX6d/1)**

To center vertically *and* horizontally, try:

```
.sq{
    width: 50%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    background: red;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/L2JUg/)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean `height:50%` or how much of the screen you want to cover. Then, you put `left:25%; top:25%; position:absolute;` and it should be centered. You may want to change absolute to fixed in the event that you want to the square to never move. You end with `.box {background-color:#000000; /*makes box black*/ height:50%/*change to 100% if want square on computer screen*/; width:50%; /*makes your box*/ left:25%; top:25%/*change this when you change height of box*/; position:absolute; /*positions your box*/}` and your HTML would be:

`<html>`
`<head>`
`<style>`
`.box {background-color:#000000; /*makes box black*/ height:50%/*change to 100% if want square on computer screen*/; width:50%; /*makes your box*/ left:25%; top:25%/*change this when you change height of box*/; position:absolute; /*positions your box*/}`
`</style>`
`</head>`
`<body>`
`<div class="box"></div>`
`</body>`
`</html>`