# Set image's height equal to dynamic width (using CSS only)

Tags: css, image, height, width, equals

Is it possible to set same height as width?

**css**

```
img{
    width:90%;
    height: same as width;
}
```

since screen width and height is not same so if width is 90% height should be same height in pix

Comment: seems duplicate question. check this SO link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout

Comment: @KheemaPandey I read that question and tried Nathan's solution. but its not work on images..

Answer (score 0):

Use width and height in pixels

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```