# HTML -- height as a percentage of the width for iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, height, width

I have an embedded sketchfab viewer on the page and want to keep an aspect ratio of 3/2.
So as an example if the Height=300px the width = 200px. The width needs to be percentage based (100% of div) and the height calculated as a percentage of the generated width.

Random guess:
**height:(66% of width);**     similar to     height:(same as width);

is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Would be easily done with LESS or SASS but I'm afraid you have to calculate it by yourself... Or you try a JavaScript solution.

Comment: maybe a jquery solution?  i was looking at this link: https://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 10):

See Sathran's answer here: [Height equal to dynamic width (CSS fluid layout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout)

The HTML:

```
<div class="model-box">
<iframe class="model" src="https://sketchfab.com/models/442c548d94744641ba279ae94b5f45ec/embed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.model-box {
  position:   relative;
  width:      100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top:   66.6%; /* This is your aspect ratio */ }

.model {
  position: absolute;
  top:      0;
  left:     0;
  bottom:   0;
  right:    0;
  width:    100%;
  height:   100%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by just CSS.

If you want to keep aspect-ratio I suggest adjusting `padding-top` percentages relative to the width %.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/5tzk3/1005/)

Adjust accordingly until you find a suitable solution for yourself.

Comment: I've tried a couple of variation but cant get it to work. heres kind of the layout but i cant get the iframe to go to height 66%.            http://jsfiddle.net/5tzk3/1008/

Answer (score -1):

For your issue I suggest you to try this. It works for me.

```html
<iframe style="position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;border:none"></iframe>
```

Comment: Please add a link and explanation to your answer