# Maintain aspect ratio according to width and height

Tags: css, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

It is possible to fit and center a square `div` in the viewport and always maintain it's **aspect ratio according to width and height**?

Requirements :

- only CSS
- the size of the square must adapt to the smallest dimension (width or height) of viewport regardless of the orientation (landscape or portrait) of the viewport.
- the square must be centered horizontaly and verticaly in the viewport

Example:

[image: Maintain aspect ratio according to width and height of viewport]

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P8cA8/).. I am not sure about the vertical though..

Comment: the outer div should be the window and the inner square should fit it, but when it is higher than wider it doesn't work

Comment: For anyone looking to do it with any div/element, you can use Container Queries. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74242757/209803

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### The aspect-ratio property (2022)

**To maintain the aspect ratio of a `div` according to width and height**, you can use the `aspect-ratio` property ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio)).
This allows you to maintain any aspect ratio according to the viewport size **or** to the size of the parent element.

**Maintaining aspect-ratio according to the viewport size (width and height) :**

```css
.ar-1-1 {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background: orange;
}

.ar-1-19 {
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  background: pink;
}

div {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
}


/** For the demo **/

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ar-1-1">Aspect ratio 1:1</div>
<div class="ar-1-19">Aspect ratio 1:19</div>
```

**Maintaining aspect ratyio according to the parent elements size (width and height) :**

```css
section {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 5vh;
  height:250px;
}
.ar-1-1 {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background: orange;
}

.ar-1-19 {
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  background: pink;
}

div {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}


/** For the demo **/

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="ar-1-1">Aspect ratio 1:1</div>
</section>
<section>
<div class="ar-1-19">Aspect ratio 1:19</div>
</section>
```

### Previous answer with vmin units

*This still works fine but it doesn't allow to maintain the aspect ratio according to a parent element size.*

**To maintain the aspect ratio of a div according to width and height** in the viewport, you can use one HTML tag with:

1. **vmin** units for the sizing :

   > **vmin** 1/100th of the minimum value between the height and the width of the viewport. 
   > (source : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths))
2. `position: absolute` and `margin: auto;` for the centering

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/pjmmqN)** (resize both window height and width to see it in action)

### Features :

- keeps it's aspect ratio according to **width and height**
- stays centered in viewport horizontaly and verticaly
- never overflows the viewport

### Browser support :

`vmin` units are supported by IE10+ ([canIuse](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)) for IE9 support, you need to use a fallback with `vm` units instead of `vmin` like this :

```
width: 100vm; /* <-- for IE9 */
height: 100vm; /* <-- for IE9 */
width: 100vmin; 
height: 100vmin;
```

### Full code:

```css
body {
  margin:0; /* To prevent scrollbars */
}

div{
  /* Aspect ratio */
  height:100vm; width:100vm; /* IE9 fallback */
  width: 100vmin; 
  height: 100vmin;
  /*Centering */
  position: absolute;
  top:0;bottom:0;
  left:0;right:0;
  margin: auto;
  /* styling */
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div>whatever content you wish</div>
```

Comment: Regarding your ie10 caution: caniuse says: Partial support in IE9 refers to supporting "vm" instead of "vmin" - so that's not applicable here because we're not using vmin

Comment: Setting the body margin to 0 is also critical

Comment: How about cases not 1:1? say, 16:9? How is vmin used for that?

Comment: @Eric I have added a more modern solution with an example for 16:9 aspect-ratio

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve a responsive square using the [**vw & vh units**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) (viewport-percentage lengths) to size it.

Check for browser support: http://caniuse.com/viewport-units

---

Solution that implements both horizontal and vertical scaling

Live sample page: http://sample.easwee.net/responsive-square/

```css
.container {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.container-row {
    display:table-row;
}

.container-cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}

.square {
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
@media(orientation:landscape) {
 .square {        
     width: 100vh;
     height: 100vh;
 }
}
@media(orientation:portrait) {
 .square{
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vw;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="container-row">
  <div class="container-cell">
      <div class="square"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mr_Green You mean vertical and horizontal simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, the size of square should be the min between width and height

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik Need to try that - will report back if I get anything solid.

Comment: @easwee - I have changed the check with `web-tiki` answer because he has achieved the same result but much simply

Answer (score 2):

I've combined the excellent answers from @ken-sharpe and @easwee to create a version for non-square aspect ratios: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyqopP

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;bottom:0;
  left:0;right:0;
  margin: auto;

  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vw;
  background: #326384;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
    div {          
        width: 200vh;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color:green;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has got to be one of the most underappreciated answers I've seen on SO. It took me hours to finally find a working solution for non-square aspect ratios. Thank you very much, sir.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I've come up with a solution with that **does need a little bit of JavaScript**, but it is sufficient for my use case. This is building on @web-tiki 's answer.

```js
let container = document.getElementById("container");

let ro = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    let {width, height} = entry.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (width > height) {
      entry.target.classList.add("widthIsGreater");
      entry.target.classList.remove("heightIsGreater");
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.add("heightIsGreater");
      entry.target.classList.remove("widthIsGreater");
    }
  }
});

ro.observe(container);
```

```css
#container {
  /* For demo */
  border: 1px solid gray;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto 5vh;
  
  /* The stuff that makes it work */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container.heightIsGreater {
  /* The stuff that makes it work */
  flex-direction: row;
}

#container.widthIsGreater {
  /* The stuff that makes it work */
  flex-direction: column;
}

#element {
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  /* The stuff that makes it work */
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="element">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use something like this

```
.container{
    display:block;
    background:#f2f2f2;
}

.square{
    width:50%;
    padding-top:50%;
    margin: auto;
    background:#e5e5e5;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8TCUQ/6/)

Comment: it doesn't work, because it use only width to set the square size