# Center and resize a container div dynamically based on image inside

Tags: html, css, dom

I need to have a container div with an image inside.

The container div must be centered horizontally AND it must only take up as much space as its content, the image, has.

The image inside must resize with the window size.

I've tried to achieve this with display: inline-block; - It works when resizing the window horizontally, but not when resizing vertically.

Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J86L9 - resize the window horizontally and vertically to see the "bug".

EDIT: Safari does it right, while Chrome does not resize the container but the image and Firefox does nothing at all. I think it could have to do with the max-height property?

```
#wrap {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    max-width: 75%;
    max-height: 75%;
}

img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: When you add a height property to the `html,body` tag, it's better : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/J86L9/1/

Comment: does not help in chrome at least, container does still not adapt to the image size after resizing the window

Comment: yes, but the image resizes according to height now.

Comment: that worked already before. its the container (marked with red border) that does not resize properly.

Comment: @alberto2000 what do you mean it's not resizing properly..? in web-tiki's fiddle it's resizing properly. Define *resizing*

Comment: @TJ in chrome or firefox: when you resize the window vertically, the container does not adapt to the new image size

Comment: is it okay that the image changes it's aspect ratio when the windows size is changed in one direction..? otherwise you'll have to write script to keep the ratio.

Comment: @TJ no the ratio must be preserved. i wanted to see if it was possibile without js

Comment: Not possible in my knowledge. you'll have to calculate the corresponding width

Comment: I have already encountered this issue, and didn't find a non-js solution but you might according to your use case. Why do you need the container to resize according to image width?

Comment: @web-tiki because i need to place other elements absolutely inside that container - it would be easy if it was possible to place elements inside a img element!

Comment: @alberto2000 ok. Do the images always have the same aspect ratio?

Comment: @web-tiki yes they do

Comment: Then you should take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23631436/1811992 it can help you maintain the aspect ratio of the image for the div.

Comment: Is this http://jsfiddle.net/J86L9/36/ what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Display the container as table is the easiest way.

**Will this work?  http://jsfiddle.net/J86L9/39/

```
body, html {margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
}
#wrap {
    display: table; width:100%; height:100%; border:1px solid red;
}
#container {
    display: table-cell; margin:0 auto; background:#ccc; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;
}

img {
    width: 50%; max-height:90%; display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: this wont adapt the height, which should be not bigger than the window... anyway I solved it with JS... dont think its possible without.

Comment: You're right, the answer was incomplete.  I added a more complete Fiddle, for any future hits on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/J86L9/42/

The "secret" is using a background image on a div rather than an img tag. This may work better for you as you mentioned in comments that you wanted other elements along with the image inside the container.

I know the border doesn't track exactly to the image but if you want that behaviour you should just set the border on your image rather than a container div.

CSS:

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;    
}

.wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper:after {
    padding-top: 150%; /*this specifies the aspect ratio*/
    display: block;
    content: '';
}

.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; /*fill parent*/
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/400/600) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```