# Make square div fill parent at all time without losing its aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

Lets say i have the following HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="square-child"></div>
</div>
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is having the `square-child` fill out as much of its parent, without losing propertions, and staying centered at all time. I have made a sketch with the `square-child`being showed in red and `parent`being showed in green.

[image]

I was reading the following SO-question, but couldn't get it centered: [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-maintain-div-aspect-ratio)

EDIT: Added fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2bg1jzg3/2

Comment: You already linked the correct answer; It looks like the current question is how to centre an element horizontally and vertically?

Comment: When i'm following the guide the square is overflowing the parent, instead of shrinking in height to fit the parent.

Comment: If the parent size is relative to the viewport, you may find an answer here: [Fit responsive square in viewport according to width and height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630140/fit-responsive-square-in-viewport-according-to-width-and-height/23631436#23631436) otherwise, you will need JS to calculate the size of the child.

Comment: Other question : what kind of content do you want to display in the child?

Comment: A background-image, see attached fiddle.

Comment: @MadsK you just got muddled up it seems, you were using the good approach with `background-size:contain;` https://jsfiddle.net/2bg1jzg3/3/

Comment: Sorry, wrong fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2bg1jzg3/2/

Comment: @MadsK you don't need anything related to the padding technique you linked to in your question. `background-size:contain;` has that feature build in http://jsfiddle.net/2bg1jzg3/4/

Comment: Sorry if i'm not being clear. I'm trying to make it square so that i "crops" the background-image by using background-size:cover; background-position: center;

Comment: @MadsK ok I see, I missunderstood. I'll delete my comments as they aren't relevant but you should add that info in the question so it makes it clear for everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this would help:
http://jsfiddle.net/2bg1jzg3/5/

```js
$(".visual").animate({
    width: "600px",
    height: "300px"
}, 2000, function () {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

```css
.visual {
    background-color:lightblue;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:250px;
    height:600px;
}
.parent {
    width:auto;
    height:100% !important;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.parent .square-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-g-850-480-8.jpg');
    width: 50%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="visual">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="square-child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool, but the square doesn't fit, as you defined it's width 50% :(

Comment: I guess the aspect ratio and the width can be done with javaScript and then it will work :)

Comment: That's true. I guess i have to use JS then.

Answer (score -2):

Try this [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/x5rfnysk/1/)

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="square-child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{
    width: 100%;
    background: #f00;   
    height: 100px;
}
.square-child{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #00FF63;
    height: 100%;
}
```