# Fixed header and footers, aspect ratio body

Tags: html, css

Thanks to a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52178548/294949), and a superb one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66721382/3245272), I've got most of the layout I'm aiming for.  Sticky, fixed height header and footer, body in the middle - centered and at a fixed aspect ratio.

The only thing not working is that the body pushes the footer off the bottom, so that it's no longer sticky.  (run snippet, scroll down to see the not-sticky-anymore footer).

The only way I've been able to affect this is by limiting the height of the `#parent` div, for example, to `80vh`.  This ends up leaving space above the footer depending on the vh.

Is there a way to do just this layout below, except keep the footer on the page?

I found a pertinent similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51665529/fixed-aspect-ratio-box-with-letter-and-pillarboxing-between-header-and-footer) on SO, but alas, unanswered.

```css
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #cffac7;
  height: 50px;
}

main {
  background-color: #55086d;
}

footer {
  background-color: #fceec7;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: auto;
}


#parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.ar-box {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: #0bf;
  aspect-ratio: 3/5; 
}

.ar-box:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  min-width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@3.0/dist/svg.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <header>header :-)</header>
  <main>
    <div id="parent">
      <div class="ar-box">body :-)</div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>footer :-(</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion, using the "aspect ratio box" as a centered position absolute element, inside a `flex: 1;` parent

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: #cffac7;
  height: 50px;
}

#parent {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
}

#aspectRatio {
  background-color: #0bf;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 3 / 5;
}
```

```html
<header>HEADER</header>
<main id="parent">
  <section id="aspectRatio">Aspect 3/5</section>
</main>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

Comment: Brilliant again! Thank you!  I'm surprised position absolute and top:0 will work together.  I would think that would place the aspectRatio element at the very top of the view.  Can you explain it?

Comment: Thank you! :) @goodson your thinking is exact. But then `margin: auto;` comes into play.

Comment: @goodson PS, I even changed/edited my other [aspect ratio answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66721382/383904) to reflect this code here, since seems to be the simplest and most flexible solution - so thanks for asking a similar question ;)

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to do this by setting the elements to be `position:fixed`.

I was able to achieve this, albeit not using flexbox styling, but nonetheless:

```
<body>
    <header/>
    <main/>
    <footer/>
</body>

------------------------

header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 50px;
}

main {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    height: calc(100% - 100px); <-- total height of header/footer
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: calc(100% - 50px);
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but doing this makes the footer disappear.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, though, can you present this as a snippet?

Comment: Header, main and footer are not void elements.