# CSS height equal to width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid-layout, aspect-ratio

Hi I have number of responsive square block elements inside of container. Every block has next css:

```
.thumbWrapper {
 display: inline-block;
 min-width: 64px;
 max-width: 128px;
 width: 23%;
 margin: 2px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 15;
}
```

Number of blocks for example 30. I put them in the container in one row, so if they not are placing in one row, part of them are moving into the next row and etc. My goal is to show to user no more then 2 rows of them. How can I do it? P.S. I could use `overflow: hidden;` property for container, but I don't know exact height of container, because it responsive depends on content blocks.

> Using just css, without JS

Example:

```
-----------------------
 __  __  __  __
 |_| |_| |_| |_|
 __  __  __  __
 |_| |_| |_| |_|
 __  __  __ 
 |_| |_| |_|                      <------------- This row should be hidden!

-----------------------
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Height equal to dynamic width (CSS fluid layout)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-a-way-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-div

Comment: Yes, I read it, but I need just using CSS, without JS.

Comment: Both links provide CSS only solutions.

Comment: You can also do something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/og8h2x5n/

Comment: Not exactly... I successfully put them like I wanted, the issue here, that I need to hide all blocks that not are placing in 2 rows...

Comment: ok, I understand your aim now. How are you etting the height of the block? are they addapting toi theire content or are you setting a specific height to them?

Comment: yes, I have square image inside of them, so they have width in %, and height according square image, so it eqivalen to width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this :

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/og8h2x5n/2/)**

```css
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
.wrap1 {
    height:0;
    padding-bottom:46%;
    position:relative;
}
.wrap2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    max-height:264px;
    min-height:136px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.wrap2 div {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 64px;
    max-width: 128px;
    width: 23%;
    margin: 2px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 15;
    background:teal;
}
div>img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap1">
    <div class="wrap2">
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-100-100-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in javascript. If you have 30 blocks then one row will have max 15 blocks,  calculate the width of first 15 block and set the width of the row to the sum of them. This would make it overflow on X direction so user have to scroll to view the hidden.

Comment: ammm... No, I mean that I need to show not all of items, I need to show, just 2 rows for example if there placing just 6 blocks, so I will show only 6 blocks and other will be hidden. And I want to do it just using css

Answer (score 0):

```
.block_list {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 128px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.a_block {
    height: 64px;
}
```

Also use `padding` not `margin` unless you add the `margin` value to the `.block_list`'s `height`

Comment: But according this solution, if responsive blocks will be 64px, there will be more than 2 rows... I added image to the task.

Comment: Ok, but they a re responsive so if there height will be 128px, so there will be just 1 row, because of: 
 min-width: 64px;
 max-width: 128px;
 width: 23%; They are dynamic because height are changing according a width

Comment: @Simha you can limit their height or their content... or if they became 128 px let it be one row... if you want a good answer try make it in a Jsfiddle ... :/