# Set image height to 75% of its container

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a responsive image list. Each image is inside a container.
I want the image container to be 75% of its first container (unit container in this case)

the image ration is 1:1

I played a little with the image container percentage width but it feels like this is not the solution.

```
<ul class="list-inline unit_list ">
<li class="unit_list_item col-xs-24 col-sm-12 col-md-8">
    <a href='#' alt="unit">
        <div class="unit_container">
            <div class="icon_container unit_icon">
                <img class="img-responsive unit_image" src="http://placehold.it/60X60" />
            </div>
            <div class="unit_name">FREE</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li></ul>
```

Btw, I'm using bootstrap if that's matter.

http://jsfiddle.net/wmu3w3ej/1/

Comment: Agree with Flopet answer, check this out  http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/wmu3w3ej/3/

Comment: `transform: scale(0.75);` to `.unit_image`? - http://jsfiddle.net/rtndqhys/

Comment: @SameeraThilakasiri It doesn't have any effect in this case because the parent doesn't have an explicit height.

Comment: Then it should give the parent an explicit height

Comment: @Mary Melody - That works but it's 75% not including the .unit_container padding.

Comment: @Flopet17 - it's responsive design. i can't give an explicit height to the parent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout DUPLICATEish. Read the answers here and you should be good. I'd recommend using the `:before` method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20117454/3389737)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Mary Melody

```
transform: scale(0.75);
```

works like magic

I'm a little afraid to use it since it's so simple.

any thoughts?

Comment: This is normally not where you ask questions, but answer them, even for yourself. Transform has good support for modern browsers look at the issues here and which browsers support it: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Answer (score 1):

Using the logic from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20117454/3389737

I have applied it to your situation: http://jsfiddle.net/phwaLmen/1/

```css
#wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper:before
{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 75%;
}

#image
{
    position: absolute;
    top:      0;
    left:     0;
    bottom:   0;
    right:    0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" id="image">
</div>
```

Add relative positioning to the parent, set its width as you'd like and make sure the overflow is hidden.

Create a `:before` element for the wrapper with a padding-top of 75%. Since there is no height specified for the `#wrapper`, this 75% is based on the width of the element :)

Then you have your image, positioned absolutely and then fitted to the container. If you want the image to be cropped instead of resized, remove the `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` style rules from it.

Comment: Thanks i tried this but it doesn't keep the aspect ration 1:1 of the image.

Comment: You asked for 75%, so it will never be 1:1 unless you use an image that is in those proportions? Also if you remove the last two styles to the image, as mentioned it crops it instead of resizing it.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (in your html):

```
<img src="img.jpg" height="75%" />
```

Good luck!