# Img height in proportion to img width, but img width is in % of parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I hope you can help me :)

I want define the height of img, in relation to the 'actual' width of the image. But the width is dynamic, because it is in % of the parent object(Browser window for an wxample) .

Why do I need the height?:
Without the height it works fine, but I need it because I want that the top of alle pictures meet at top and my pictures have different proportion. (I know that this will compress the pictures... later I fix this with overflow, after I have an solution for the height problem).

How I imagine, I need something that gives returns me the px of the 'actual'(for an example, after the user changed the size of the browser window) width. And then I can multiply it by 3 and write that to the height. (for an proportion of 1to3)

Comment: http://bashooka.com/coding/responsive-jquery-image-gallery-plugins/

Comment: thx for the first answer, but i already have a 'image gallery' ... fancybox. That what I'm looking for is the pictures who are showed on the website directly before somebody clicks it. ... for that im doing a row of 3 or 4 picture. The width is in % of parent table and the table is in % of the 'document'(browser). Anything is fine, I only need a solution for the height if the proportion of the thumbnails is different. Excample(2014.11.20): http://torbenkaehler.de/index.php?content=fotos_halloween_fahrt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you all you need.

```
var img = document.getElementById('testImage');

// these vars are numbers representing a length in pixel
var w = img.width, h = img.height; // displayed dimensions, change on resize
var nw = img.naturalWidth, nh = img.naturalHeight; // dimensions of the original image file

var proportion = nh / nw; // proportion < 1 : 'portrait', < 1 : 'landscape'
```

Since width / height change on resize you have to update them in the moment you need them.

Comment: @Terry: Thanks for fixing my typo!

Comment: Thx for this good answer. It worked for me generelly(and so it is the answerto my question), but I had the problem that I don't know the Id of all Elements/Images(dynamicly created). But on this way i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout . It is nearly the same question, but the solution goes over css-classes.