# Make button same width as height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a toolbar on the top of my website, which is a `fixed div`. In there I have another `div`, with some buttons in it:

```
|somethingsomething.com                                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|statusBar____________________________________________|buttons|
|rest of website                                              |
```

HTML:

```
<div class="statusBar">
    <div class="statusBarMenuButtons">
        <form class="homeButtonForm" action="?id=1" method="post"><button class="homeButton"></button></form>
        <form class="subscriptionsButtonForm" action="?id=2" method="post"><button class="subscriptionsButton"></button></form>
        <form class="searchButtonForm" action="?id=3" method="post"><button class="searchButton"></button></form>                   
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.statusBar{  
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:5%;
}

button{
    height:100%;
    margin-right:10px;
}

form{
    height:100%;
}

/* This is the same for all buttons, just different background-images */
button.homeButton{
    background:url(../resources/homeButton.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:auto 100%; /* width height */
}
```

Now, my problem is that I have no way of knowing which `height` the button will get, and therefore cannot know which `width` I should specify.

I have search a lot on this website and Google and found lots of answers about `div`s, also I found this `jQuery`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var height = $('button.homeButton').height();
    $('button.homeButton').css({
        'width' : height + 'px';
    });
</script>
```

But it does not seem to work. I have pulled this snippet form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout) and thought maybe the problem was that I am using a button instead of a div.

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2krfsweh/) This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2krfsweh/1/) is with the class you wanted

```js
var height = $('button.homeButton').height();
$('button').width(height);
```

```css
div.statusBar {
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:5%;
}
button {
    height:100px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
form {
    height:100%;
}
/* This is the same for all buttons, just different background-images */
 button.homeButton {
    background:url(../resources/homeButton.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:auto 100%;
    /* width height */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="statusBar">
    <div class="statusBarMenuButtons">
        <form class="homeButtonForm" action="?id=1" method="post">
            <button class="homeButton"></button>
        </form>
        <form class="subscriptionsButtonForm" action="?id=2" method="post">
            <button class="subscriptionsButton"></button>
        </form>
        <form class="searchButtonForm" action="?id=3" method="post">
            <button class="searchButton"></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Result: http://imgur.com/vyIW5je. Does come closer, still 6px of though, any thoughts on that? EDIT: It looks like the margin is messing it up, if you look at the orange square. ANOTHER EDIT: Found problem, was using old version of `jQuery`. Current result is great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JS.

`div.statusBar` will take the height from child elements. If form or button don't have a fixed height, it won't work. Using `height:5%;` is taking height from body or html, which may be undefined.

Try adding a fixed height to div.statusBar

```
div.statusBar {
   height: 60px;
}
```

Also, add `display: block;` to the `button` to apply width and height properties correctly.

Comment: The whole point of the `height:5%` in `div.statusBar` is to make sure that even on large or small screens the `statusBar` is the same size. With an absolute size this won't work.