# Have one CSS attribute equal another attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a personal website and would like to have it so what ever the width of one element is the height is always equal.

The width is set as a percentage so will change based on the window size.

I imagine I could use JS to do this but would prefer not to.

Comment: What's your question? You mean to say, equal height and width, is it?

Comment: Yeah I want to be able to use the width as the height but width is a percentage

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5445491/462627

Comment: You will need to use javascript to accomplish this. The closest you can get with just CSS is having static sizes. Perhaps look into SASS or LESS or another CSS preprocessor. They will provide shortcuts for things like this.

Comment: Hi, i posted a new answer or hack (pure HTML and CSS) here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32870380/1661983