# Javascript to keep menu open during navigation in submenu

Tags: javascript, menu

first, thank you for helping me creating the following menu of little squares that open and display sublinks on hover (original question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892979/css-html-javascript-accordeon-menu-display-sublist-inside-parent-square)). 
Now, I would like to achieve the following: when I klick on (not hover over) "a", I would like the square to "open" up and display the sublinks. I would also like the square to stay "open" while I klick and navigate around the submenus (a1, a2...)...also when I click on the content/on other parts of my site, if possible. I want the square to only shrink back to its starting size only when I click on a different square ("b").
I know I need javascript for this, and have looked at some scripts I found on the internet, but I unfortunately understand too little about javascript to be able to adapt them to my own menu (what I found is usually for "normal" dropdown or accordeon menus but I have no idea at all what I need to do with it to make it work with my menu as what I have is not exactly the same).
Thanks in advance !

```css
#hideme{display:none;}

.menu  ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
}

.menu  li {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
 color:white;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: bottom; vertical-align: bottom;
}


.menu > li ul li{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin-left:20px;
 margin-top:5px;
    list-style:none;
 text-decoration: none;
    text-align: bottom; vertical-align: bottom;
}

ul.menu > li {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:90px;
 min-height:90px;
    max-height:90px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background:#5DB26E;
    color:#5DB26E;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:all 0s ease;
 
}


ul.menu > li:hover {
    width:180px;
 min-height:180px;
 color: white;
    border: 3px solid white;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #5DB26E;
  position: relative;
}

ul.menu> li:hover #hideme{display:block;  position: absolute;
    bottom: 10;}
ul.menu> li:hover .fa-arrow-right{content: "\f023";}

.hoverme:hover .fa-arrow-right,
.hoverme .fa-check {
    display: none;
}
.hoverme:hover .fa-check {
    display: inline;
}

 
.menu a {
    margin:0;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu"> 
<li> <a href="a.html"><b>a</b></a>
      <ul> <span id ="hideme">
        <li><a href="a1.html" class="hoverme"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;a111111111111111</a></li>
        <li><a href="a2.html" class="hoverme"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;a2222222222222</a></li></span>
      </ul>
    </li>
<li> <a href="b.html"><b>b</b></a>
      <ul> <span id ="hideme">
        <li><a href="b1.html" class="hoverme"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;b1</a></li>
        <li><a href="b2.html" class="hoverme"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;b2</a></li></span>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You ul s have the same ids. Use jquery click and addClass.

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand what you're trying to explain to me...can you give me more information or edit my codesnippet? I don't have any knowledge about javascript (and understand very little about how it works) - if I did I would be able to adapt the scripts I found on the net :-(

Comment: Take out the span inside ul. Set ul ids as unique. Use jquery click : https://api.jquery.com/click/. And jquery addclass: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/. Bazillion  of examples over google and stackoverflow. Use the search.

Comment: Dont try to reinvent the wheel. Use boostrap. https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: I can't take out the span inside the ul because otherwise my sublinks will not be hidden **scatcheshead**...in reality my linktexts are very long...

Comment: anyone else ? PLEASE ?