# Restrict width in relation to the height and vice versa

Tags: html, css

Using CSS I would like to restrict 1 dimension to never exceed a factor of the other.

For example this pseudocode:

```
max-height: (width * 0.75)px;
```

Would ensure that the height of the element never exceeds 75% of it's width, but it may be smaller.

Is something like this possible, or am I out of luck?

**Edit:** Please note that I'm *not* looking to make the height *exactly* 75% of the width, but rather I am looking to make sure it doesn't *exceed* 75%

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

Comment: This is called the aspect ratio fyi

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be a matter of preserving aspect ratio, but not to exceed some aspect ratio, that is different.

Answer (score 2):

If the element takes the entire **viewport** width. You can do something like:

```
.class {
  max-height: 75vw;
}
```

Comment: I guess that always refers to the entire viewport, and not the parent element? Clever though, I might still be able to use that and might solve my problem if there's not a better solution.

Comment: You are right. Or if the element is using vw too, or % relative to the viewport, you'll then have to do a calc() or set the max height manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the ratio, but there's always `padding-bottom`!

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
}
```

This code will set `div` to 4:3 ratio

For 16:9 ratio use `padding-bottom: 56.25%`

**An edit after re-read**

What if I suggest using a div inside a div?

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">

  </div>
</div>
<style>
.a{
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
.b{
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Put the content inside `div.b` and it will never exceed the 75%

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro that's correct. I actually intend to restrict the aspect ratio for both dimensions. Ultimately I want my div to take up 4:3 or 16:9 but not let the aspect ratio diverge further than those two. Those are my ultimate relative bounding boxes.

Comment: @Nordenheim I do appreciate, you still didn't read the other comment or my original post well. I'm looking to control `max-height`, your solution would be correct if I was just looking for `height`.

Comment: Thanks that might work! I tried to wrap my head around it, but I guess this would even work if the parent `width` is not 100%, which is ultimately the goal. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

CSS does not allow setting a property based on other's value, you would need to use another approach, such as javascript, for this.

Here's a jQuery example:

```
var $elem = $('#elem');
$elem.css('max-height', $elem.width() * 0.75 );
```

Comment: It's a valid solution, but would be a lot worse to do it this way. It means I have to listen for resize events as well to make sure it stays accurate, and whenever the DOM reflows (it's a fairly dynamic application). Still a good answer for cases where it's not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question: [Height equal to dynamic width (CSS fluid layout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout)

Specifically @Kristijan's answer. You will need to adjust the bottom padding.

```
.some_element {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I'm looking to use it as a `max-height` not `height`. If it was `height`, you would be right though.