# Aspect Ratio Hell with a Twisted Math Puzzle (Css Only)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

I have a `4:3` parent, and a child shrinked and centered. Finally a `4:3` child inside.

```css
.table {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.top {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  right: 15%;
  top: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
  background: yellow;
}
.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 50%;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  4:3
  <div class="top">
    <div class="item">4:3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- `.table` has a `4:3` aspect ratio
- `.top` is distanced by equal amount from the edges of .table
- `.item` should have a `4:3` aspect ratio

In this code `.top` is centered and distanced equal from `.table`.
**Problem is `.item` doesn't have `4:3` aspect ratio**. (I gave it arbitrary `height`, `width`). Here's an [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGwVpP).

*Note: `.top` is preferred to be distanced equal, it may be close to equal.*

Comment: @web-tiki, see the example, `.top` is centered and distanced equal. The problem is the `.item`, it doesn't have `4:3` aspect ratio in my example.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with CSS only and the padding-bottom technique to [maintain the aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css) of the elements.  It relies on the fact that percentage padding is calculated according to the with of the container ([w3.org reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#padding-properties)).

In the following example, I applied the aspect ratio on the `.top` element (centered it with absolute positioning and `margin:auto;` ) this way, you can size `.item` with `width:100%; height:100%;` as `.top` already has a 4:3 aspect ratio:

```css
.table {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
.top {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 52.25%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: yellow;
}
.item {
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">4:3
  <div class="top">
    <div class="item">4:3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This technique also allows you to make the elements responsive by applying the padding technique to the `.table` element too:

```css
.table {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom:22.5%;
}
.top {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 52.25%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: yellow;
}
.item {
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">4:3
  <div class="top">
    <div class="item">4:3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use margin for `.top`:

```
.top {
    margin: auto xx auto xx; /* top right bottom left */
}
```

And then you could set width and height of item:

```
.item{
    height: 200px; /* example */
}
```

And then you use jQuery to set width:

```
var cw = $('.item').width();
$('.item').css({'height': 1.2 * cw +'px'});
```

Comment: Also, you could check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6615994/4037019