# How to set equal height and width based on dynamic text using CSS only

Tags: css

Using CSS only, if you `<div>Some dynamic text</div>`, how do you make the height and width of the `div` equal dimensions when the `width` is determined by the dynamic text?

Comment: I see plenty of questions/answers on how to set equal dimensions using css only, but none that are based on the dynamic content. I have provided an answer in hopes that it will help someone else that ran into the same issue as myself.

Comment: Post some more code please or probably create a fiddle with the problem statement perhaps. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a single paragraph element inside a `div` and give the `p` a `margin` using `calc()` which takes into account the `width` of the `div` (because `%` is always based on the `width` of the parent element).

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
display: inline-block;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
padding: 6px;
}

p {
margin: calc(50% - 12px) 0; /* half the width minus half the line-height */
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p contenteditable="true">Click me &amp; edit to change div size.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm... I thought this was even simpler than yours, @DerekStory, but on second thoughts, comparing the two, it ends up looking very similar. Say if you'd prefer me to delete this alternative and I'll be happy to oblige.

Comment: I really like this and think it is a bit more straight forward. I'll keep both just for a reference, but marking yours as the correct answer and +1.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to setting equal height based on the known width as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6615994/2479962

You first contain the dynamic text within a container and add a margin pusher (in this case `:before`) above the dynamic text element:

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dAebS/586/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="element">
       Dimensions set by content.
    </div>
</div>
```

The trick is to base `.element:before`'s margin off the dynamic contents `font-size` and `padding`:

**CSS Only:**

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: silver;
}
.element {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    /* So we don't have to take line-height into consideration during calc() */
    line-height: 1; 
}
.element:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    /*  100% is for 1:1 aspect ratio */
    /* 20px is taking the contents font-size plus the padding on each side */
    margin-top: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

---

With @Rounin's suggestion, we can vertically center it using both `:before` and `:after` and dividing the calculations by two:

[JS Fiddle - Vertically centered](http://jsfiddle.net/dAebS/588/)

```
.element:before, .element:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  /*  100% is for 1:1 aspect ratio */
  /* 10px is taking the contents font-size plus the padding on each side/2 */
  margin-top: calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

Comment: Very clever. +1. To vertically center the text, we can place one `.dimension-setter` above `#element` and one below and update the style declaration to: `margin: calc(50% - 20px) 0;`

Comment: Great idea. Fiddle using your suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/dAebS/582/