# Why there is a gap between div and rotated div (triangle)

Tags: html, css, rotation, rectangles

I am trying to do this shape in HTML/CSS for my mobile app:
 https://embed.plnkr.co/9k8jbJyzUiSMSoSHlOti/

```css
.boundary {
  width: 100.13723%;
  padding-bottom: 5.24078%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.boundary:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  background-color: green;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="boundary"></div>
<div class="inner">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis auteirure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

In my browser, when I inspect the element and change the zoom (to 75%), there is a gap between 2 `<div>`.  When I deploy my application in my device, I can see this same gap.

What is going on ?

[image: result : make triangle with rectangle transformation (rotate)]

This is how I make the shape:

- I create a first div to do the inclined line. I make a responsive triangle (I picked some information from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work))

  1) In my div, I insert a first pseudo-element and give it 100% width and height of parent. I apply a rotation : I define a transform origin in the top left, and rotate the pseudo element 3 degrees clockwise with `transform: rotate(3deg)`

  2) I have to adjust width and height: I use percentages and `padding-bottom` to maintain the aspect ratio ([more information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout)) so:

`[rectangle height] : padding-bottom = tan(3deg) * 100% = 100.13723% (100% is the screen width)
[hypotenuse of triangle = new rectangle width] : width = tan(3deg) * 100% / sin(3deg) = 5.24078%.`

3) To hide the unwanted parts of the pseudo element (everything that overflows the `<div>` with the red border) I set `overflow: hidden` on the container.

- I make a second `<div>` after the first inclined `<div>`. This `<div>` is simple, without special transformation, and contains *Lorem ipsum*.

Comment: the weird thing for me, using Chrome, is that the weird line only shows up in "inspect" mode, but not the rest of the time.

Answer (score 6):

This usually happens while transforming elements because browser starts doing antialiasing with elements' edges.

> Antialiasing is something of an unsung hero in web graphics; it’s the
>   reason we have clear text and smooth vector shapes on our screens.

While zooming out/in browser doesn't rescale  element properly, e.g. if you zoom out an element of `1px` height  to `0.75%`, browser should redraw element to `0.75px` but browser cannot draw `0.75px`, it either can create it `1` or it will try to make edges smooth with making pixel blur or 50% opacity.

---

[image]

In above picture you can see the same triangle being drawn, but on the left it has antialiasing enabled and on the right it’s been disabled. As you can see, when antialiasing is enabled the pixels are shades of gray when the triangle only passes through part of the pixel. When disabled, however, the pixel is filled in as either solid black or solid white and the shape looks jagged.

---

Using  [**`backface-visibility: hidden;`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility) or overlapping elements with negative margins while scaling/transforming is the better option to avoid this issue.

**Demo without using `backface-visibility: hidden;`**

```css
html,
body {
  transform: scale(.8);
}

.boundary {
  width: 100.13723%;
  padding-bottom: 5.24078%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.boundary:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  background-color: green;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="boundary"></div>
<div class="inner">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

---

**Demo with using `backface-visibility: hidden;`**

```css
html,
body {
  transform: scale(.8);
}

.boundary {
  width: 100.13723%;
  padding-bottom: 5.24078%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.boundary:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  background-color: green;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="boundary"></div>
<div class="inner">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

---

**Demo provided by [OP in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054056/why-there-is-a-gap-between-div-and-rotated-div-triangle/#comment77666902_45303840) solved by using `backface-visibility: hidden;` and overlapping elements with `negative margin`**

```css
html,
body {
  transform: scale(.75);
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.inner-2 {
  background-color: red;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.inner-3 {
  background-color: blue;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.boundary {
  width: 100.13723%;
  padding-bottom: 5.24078%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.boundary:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  background-color: green;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.boundary-2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.boundary-2:before {
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
  background-color: red;
}

.boundary-3 {
  background-color: red;
}

.boundary-3:before {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="boundary"></div>
<div class="inner">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

<div class="boundary boundary-2"></div>
<div class="inner inner-2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

<div class="boundary boundary-3"></div>
<div class="inner inner-3">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

PS: Don't forget to use `viewport meta` tag for responsiveness.

**Source** [Antialiasing-101](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/antialiasing-101/)

Comment: It seems to work but not without adding few new issues (happening after a scroll)... Unfortunately, we cannot reproduce them on the plnkr, which is a simplified version of what we really have. Keep you in touch ASAP

Comment: @SébastienBATEZAT Using `backface-visibility: hidden;` is working for given example in OP's question, if this is not working in your case there would be any other issue, if possible provide working demo or raw code.

Comment: @Downvoter, Comment your reason for downvote so I can improve my answer.

Comment: works for me, but now there is a weird stepped effect on the top slope of `div.boundary`

Comment: It seems to work but when I add 2 shapes below the first shape there is a gap between 2 div. Why ? see here : https://embed.plnkr.co/9k8jbJyzUiSMSoSHlOti/

Comment: @sophie Update my answer, check once.

Comment: We are using (from the beginning) that viewport : 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
I guess it's the reason of our issue (from what you said : browser redraw our elements). So how to fix the issue when there is more than one div (see above plunkr from Sophie)?

Comment: @sophie Where is problem now?, if  you see the last snippet in my answer, it's solving the issue of code provided by you.

Comment: `backface-visibility: hidden;` and overlapping elements with `negative-margin` is the only solution for this kind of issues I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have fixed it by using skew and adding a border and a negative margin at the top.

Here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/vogelbeere/pen/oeXrpd) and below is my CSS:

```
.boundary {
    padding-bottom: 5.24078%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}

.boundary:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 105%;
  height: 105%;
  transform-origin: top left;
  background-color: green;
  transform: skew(0, 3deg);
  z-index: 10;
}


.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 50;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid green;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gap is still there even if you do not apply any transformation.

```css
.boundary {
  width: 100.13723%;
  padding-bottom: 5.24078%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.boundary:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*transform-origin: top left;*/
  /*transform: rotate(3deg);*/
  background-color: green;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="boundary"></div>
<div class="inner">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis auteirure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

So `transform:rotate()` or something are not causing any troubles.
Now your problem can be solved by

```
.inner {
  margin-top: -2px;
  /* experiment different value or unit for different zoom levels*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For me it is rendering problem. If you change

```
top: 0px;
```

to

```
top: 1px;
```

everything should be fine.

Comment: Doesn't seems to be better with top: 1px (just tested on the given plnkr, have you tried?).
Very weird issue BTW.