# css clip-path little gap between

Tags: html, css, clip-path

The code is below.
[gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VulSS.png)
there is a very small gap between two divs.but it should not have.

```css
.gra {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.left {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, red 0%, blue 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

.right {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, red 0%, blue 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class='gra left'></div>
<div class='gra right'></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add more details about the context of your question to make it easier to understand for others. Consider adding information or screenshots of your desired vs. the actual output of your application. Also, have a look at [this help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because of [Antialiasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054056/why-there-is-a-gap-between-div-and-rotated-div-triangle/45303840#45303840).

Use `left:0;` with the left class and `left: -1px;` with the right class to overlap Antialiasing

```css
.gra {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.left {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, red 0%, blue 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  left:0;
}

.right {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, red 0%, blue 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class='gra left'></div>
<div class='gra right'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change by:

```
clip-path: polygon(-1% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 101%);
```

```css
.gra {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.left {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, red 0%, blue 100%) ;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

.right {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, red 0%, blue 101%);
  clip-path: polygon(-1% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 101%);
}
```

```html
<div class='gra left'></div>
<div class='gra right'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, another way:

```css
.gra {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.left {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, red 0%, blue 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:201px;
  height:201px;
}

.right {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, red 0%, blue 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:201px;
  height:201px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gra">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea without `clip-path` where you will have a better support, less of code and no gap issue

```css
.container {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, red 0%, blue 100%);
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, red 0%, blue 100%);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding a half pixel to the 100% values.

Change:

`clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);`

To:

`clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% calc(100% + 0.5px), 100% calc(100% + 0.5px));`

If you need to fix a gap on the top, you could change `0%` to `calc(0% - 0.5px)`.