# How can I add a 1px border to an image without a gap?

Tags: html, css

I would like to draw a border around an image with no visible gap between the image and the border.

```css
img{
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://files.catbox.moe/r099uw.png">
```

Result of above snippet in Chrome (Version 84):
[image: result of above snippet]

There is a small gap between the image and the border to the right and below the image.

[The answer to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image) suggests setting `display: block` on the image, but this does not seem to solve the problem in this case. Based on other answers I have also tried `vertical-align:bottom`, `padding:0`, `margin: 0;` adding `width/height`, but all to no avail. Increasing the border to 2px gets rid of the gap, but is not an ideal solution.

I tested the above snippet in Chrome, Firefox, and Microsoft Edge. It displays without a gap in Firefox, but with a gap in Chrome and Edge.

How can I create a bordered image that displays consistently without a gap across all platforms?

Comment: What version of Chrome?

Comment: @sol Version 84.0.4147.89 on Windows 10.

Comment: If you zoom in, you'll not see any white space, maybe it's because of [Antialiasing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45303840/6670723)

Comment: The image is 16x16, there wouldn't be any anti-aliasing. @AbhishekPandey

Comment: I can see the problem when I zoom in. Can you use `outline` instead of `border`?

Comment: @ChloeDev it is antialiasing, if you increase width of image by `1px` the white space will be gone.

Comment: @sol Using `outline` instead of `border` does seem to fix the issue. It is not a perfect solution, as the outline expands beyond the content box. This can be compensated for by offsetting the image position by 1px, although that feels a bit hacky.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that adding `box-sizing: border-box;` as well as a specific `height` solves the problem in Chrome and Edge.

```css
img{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://files.catbox.moe/r099uw.png">
```

If anybody knows a better solution, or why this is necessary, please let me know.

Edit: This solution is not perfect, as the gap can reappear depending on the position of the image. For example:

```css
img{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
}

span{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<span>
<img src="https://files.catbox.moe/r099uw.png">
</span>
```

Result in Chrome (zoomed in for detail):
[image]

Comment: `box-sizing` determines whether the border and padding should be added to the width (`100% + border-width + padding`) or if the border and padding should be within the 100% width and height. As a Chromium user, I didn't experience the issue you do with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this with `css` styling. This is what we can do, let's define a css `class` or `id` with desired `width` and `height` that you would like to have for `image`. Now use your `image` as `background` for defined `div` or `class`. `Stroke/Border` effect can be done by giving `border` to defined `class` or `id`. Once you're done you can `adjust` your `image` by making some changes to `background-size`. That will make you image `zoom in` or `zoom out`. So you can easily cover up the `gap` for any `image`. Here is the code

HTML :

```
<div id="image"> </div>
```

CSS :

```
#image {
display:inline-block;
width:30px;
height:30px;
border:1px solid #000;
background-image:url(TOn2E.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: 150%
}
```

For adjusting image you can make changes to background-size in percentage.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
img {
   outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://files.catbox.moe/r099uw.png">
```

Also, if necessary, try to append `outline-offset`, like `outline-offset: -1px;`