# Maintain aspect ratio of elements within a fluid CSS grid layout

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, css-grid

I have a list of div elements in a 4-column CSS grid layout. The div elements are set to 100% width, with a padding-top of 100% to maintain an aspect ratio of 1:1. This is a common technique, as can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6615994/7949834

This works in Firefox, but not in Chrome. In Chrome the elements do not take up any space within the grid container. What is the reason for this?

```css
ul {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5%;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}

div {
  background-color: green;
  padding-top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ab0asum3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be 2 issues:

- `auto` is not a valid value for `grid-template-columns` - use something like `1fr`
- using a percentage value for the `grid-gap` when no explicit height has been defined for the `li` or `div`

You'll need to use a pixel value for the row gap.

```css
ul {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px 5%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: green;
  padding-top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you nailed this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm still learning CSS Grid myself, so I could be wrong. Using percentage vakues on other elements without an explicitly defined height is usually problematic. And it seems to fix the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

```css
/* change --grid-aspect-ratio to your aspect ratio*/
:root {
  --grid-aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}

/* Consider using div element for grid */
ul {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  list-style-type: none;
}
/* Consider using div element for grid-cell */
li {
  /* set relative position */
  position: relative;
  background-color: lime;
}

li:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: calc( 100% / (var(--grid-aspect-ratio)));
}
/* wrap your content in <div class="grid-cell-inner"> */
.grid-cell-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

It is better to use div elements for grid.
Note that you will have to use some inner element for grid cell content and set it`s position to absolute to maintain the same aspect ratio.
Dont use % for grid gap, if it is relative to viewport you can use vw/vh units.

Answer (score 0):

you should use [1fr](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#algo-find-fr-size) instead [auto](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#valdef-grid-template-columns-auto) to size your columns :

```css
ul {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:nth-child(4n)~li {
  /* eventually for the gap missing in chrome */
  margin-top: 5%
}

div {
  background-color: green;
  padding-top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Note: for the square technic, unlike flex it can be made from the grid child and it can allow you to fill div with content and center it example https://jsfiddle.net/ab0asum3/4/

Answer (score -1):

If you open the Chome DevTools and inspect the `divs` you'll see that the browser is computing their height as **0px.** I can't say exactly which quirk or which standard you're breaking here, but if the nested `divs` don't have a height, they won't impart anything on their parent `lis` and you won't have anything displayed.

The **reason** is that Chrome computes the nested `div` with **zero height**, which in turn means the parent `li` will have **zero height**. That's your why.

Comment: Both Firefox and Chrome compute the nested div with zero height. But the effective height should also be a result of the padding, which Firefox takes into account, Chrome doesn't. I'm not sure which implementation is correct here. Thanks for the comment, I'm not sure why you were downvoted.

Comment: it's a weird edge case, maybe the drive-by downvote is just unfamiliar with it. you might want to go digging for rendering rules for FF and Chrome and see why they differ on padding/zero-height contradictions.